# Why SQLite make BLOB from my integer?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In this string I put index from Spinner to database:

```
values.put(LinkDbHelper.COLUMN_TYPE, spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

But when I check .db file on my phone, I see BLOB.
Why BLOB if type of this field is INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT?

Full create table string:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_TYPE + " INTEGER  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_LINK + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_IMAGE + " BLOB);"
```

Comment: How exactly do you check the .db file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you problem is that somehow you have actually stored a blob in COLUMN_TYPE.

SQLite is pretty flexible, including the ability to store any type of data anywhere (excpetion below) as per:-

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY
>   KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.
>   [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3 - 2. Storage Classes and Datatypes](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

I've done some testing and come up with the following results:-

```
09-09 15:27:31.347 5114-5114/? D/TBCRT: CREATE TABLE table1(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, alt1 BLOB, name TEXT NOT NULL, link TEXT NOT NULL, image BLOB)
09-09 15:27:31.365 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO: Row 0
09-09 15:27:31.366 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO:    
                                         Column Name=_id   Value=1  
                                         Column Name=type   Value=unobtainable  
                                         Column Name=alt1   Value=unobtainable  
                                         Column Name=name   Value=1504934851322 
                                         Column Name=link   Value=10101111001100101000110110111001011111010 
                                         Column Name=image   Value=2.45678  
                                         Column Name=TYPE_TYPECOLUMN   Value=blob   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_ALT1COLUMN   Value=blob   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_NAMECOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_LINKCOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_IMAGECOLUMN   Value=real
09-09 15:27:31.366 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO: Row 1
09-09 15:27:31.366 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO:    
                                         Column Name=_id   Value=2  
                                         Column Name=type   Value=-1    
                                         Column Name=alt1   Value=-1    
                                         Column Name=name   Value=FRED  
                                         Column Name=link   Value=MYLINK    
                                         Column Name=image   Value=unobtainable 
                                         Column Name=TYPE_TYPECOLUMN   Value=integer    
                                         Column Name=TYPE_ALT1COLUMN   Value=integer    
                                         Column Name=TYPE_NAMECOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_LINKCOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_IMAGECOLUMN   Value=blob
09-09 15:27:31.366 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO: Row 2
09-09 15:27:31.366 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO:    
                                         Column Name=_id   Value=3  
                                         Column Name=type   Value=0 
                                         Column Name=alt1   Value=100   
                                         Column Name=name   Value=Bert  
                                         Column Name=link   Value=noweher   
                                         Column Name=image   Value=unobtainable 
                                         Column Name=TYPE_TYPECOLUMN   Value=integer    
                                         Column Name=TYPE_ALT1COLUMN   Value=integer    
                                         Column Name=TYPE_NAMECOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_LINKCOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_IMAGECOLUMN   Value=blob
09-09 15:27:31.366 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO: Row 3
09-09 15:27:31.366 5114-5114/? D/DBINFO:    
                                         Column Name=_id   Value=4  
                                         Column Name=type   Value=unobtainable  
                                         Column Name=alt1   Value=unobtainable  
                                         Column Name=name   Value=1504934851362 
                                         Column Name=link   Value=10101111001100101000110110111001100100010 
                                         Column Name=image   Value=2.45678  
                                         Column Name=TYPE_TYPECOLUMN   Value=blob   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_ALT1COLUMN   Value=blob   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_NAMECOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_LINKCOLUMN   Value=text   
                                         Column Name=TYPE_IMAGECOLUMN   Value=real
```

As the first line shows the **type** column was created using **`INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`**, the **alt1** column was created using **`BLOB`**.

The output for row 0 indicates that the **type** column has a type of **blob**, but for row 1 however shows that **type** has a type of **integer**. Row 2 reflects the same types as row 1 and row 3 the same as row 0.

Note! the Cursor `getString` method will throw an exception if used for trying to get a BLOB, so in this situation the value is shown as **unobtainable**

In short you can see how dynamic the column types are and also that what you specify when you create the table is not a hard and fast (static type).

To achieve the above I used the following in a DBHelper :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DBNNAME = "mydatabase";
    private static final int DBVESRION = 1;
    private static final String TABLENAME = "table1";
    private static final String IDCOLUMN = "_id";
    private static final String TYPECOLUMN = "type";
    private static final String ALT1COLUMN = "alt1";
    private static final String NAMECOLUMN = "name";
    private static final String LINKCOLUMN = "link";
    private static final String IMAGECOLUMN = "image";

    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNNAME, null, DBVESRION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME + "(" +
                IDCOLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                TYPECOLUMN + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                ALT1COLUMN + " BLOB, " +
                NAMECOLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                LINKCOLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                IMAGECOLUMN + " BLOB" +
                ")";
        Log.d("TBCRT",crtsql);
        db.execSQL(crtsql);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion){

    }
```

..... (more to come)

The above code creating the Database and the single table as per :-

`CREATE TABLE table1(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, alt1 BLOB, name TEXT NOT NULL, link TEXT NOT NULL, image BLOB)`

The code above being followed by 3 methods:-

**`insertRow`** - to insert a row as one typically would.

```
public void insertRow(int type, int alt, String name, String link, byte[] image) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TYPECOLUMN,type);
    cv.put(ALT1COLUMN,alt);
    cv.put(NAMECOLUMN,name);
    cv.put(LINKCOLUMN,link);
    cv.put(IMAGECOLUMN,image);

    this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLENAME,null,cv);
}
```

**`insertAlternativeRow`** to insert rows with forced types.

```
public void insertAlternativeRow() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TYPECOLUMN,new byte[]{100,100,100,100,100});
    cv.put(ALT1COLUMN,new byte[]{25,25,25,25,25,25,67,45,23,43,17,89,56,34,32,111,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,
            25,25,25,25,25,67,45,23,43,17,89,56,34,32,111,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,
            25,25,25,25,25,67,45,23,43,17,89,56,34,32,111,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
            ,25,25,25,25,25,67,45,23,43,17,89,56,34,32,111,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
            ,25,25,25,25,25,67,45,23,43,17,89,56,34,32,111,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
            ,25,25,25,25,25,67,45,23,43,17,89,56,34,32,111,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
            ,25,25,25,25,25,67,45,23,43,17,89,56,34,32,111,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91});
    cv.put(NAMECOLUMN,Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    cv.put(LINKCOLUMN,Long.toBinaryString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    cv.put(IMAGECOLUMN,2.45678d);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLENAME,null,cv);
}
```

**`viewRowsWithTypes`** to output rows with column name, value stored and column types as per the `typeof` function.

```
public Cursor viewRowsWithTypes() {
     return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLENAME,
            new String[] {
            "*, " +
                    "typeof(" + TYPECOLUMN + ") AS TYPE_TYPECOLUMN, " +
                    "typeof(" + ALT1COLUMN + ") AS TYPE_ALT1COLUMN, " +
                    "typeof(" + NAMECOLUMN + ") AS TYPE_NAMECOLUMN, " +
                    "typeof(" + LINKCOLUMN + ") AS TYPE_LINKCOLUMN, " +
                    "typeof(" + IMAGECOLUMN + ") AS TYPE_IMAGECOLUMN "
    },
            null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

In **`activty_main.xml`** I coded a basic spinner giving it an id of **myspinner**.

In **`MainActivity`** I coded :-

```
    myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
    dbhlpr.insertAlternativeRow(); //Insert a row with forced types
    dbhlpr.insertRow(myspinner.getSelectedItemPosition(),
            myspinner.getSelectedItemPosition(),
            "FRED","MYLINK",new byte[]{0,7,5,4,3,2,8,10,16,32,64,127});
    dbhlpr.insertRow(0,100,"Bert","noweher",new byte[]{100,100,100,100,100});
    dbhlpr.insertAlternativeRow();
    Cursor csr = dbhlpr.viewRowsWithTypes();
    String logdata;
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Row " + csr.getPosition());
        logdata = "";
        for (int i =0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            String val;
            try {
                val = csr.getString(i);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                val = "unobtainable";
            }
            logdata = logdata + "\t\nColumn Name=" +
                    csr.getColumnName(i) +
                    "   Value=" + val;
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO",logdata);
    }
    csr.close();
```

So the first row (row 0) was inserted using forced types i.e. effectively BLOB data for columns **type** and **alt1**.

The second row (row 1) was inserted using the typical insert with columns **type** and alt1 getting their values via the Spinner **`getSelectedItemPosition`** method (noting that the Spinner was not populated, hence -1).

The third row (row 2) was insert, again using the typical insert within columns **type** and **alt1** being given direct values (0 and 100).

The last row (row 3) was just a replication of the first row.

The **`viewRowsWithTypes`** method was then called returning a Cursor, this was then traversed to output the Row being processed, followed by a line for each column with the column name, the data in the column (note only getString was used). Note that the columns **TYPE_????** holding a value that reflects SQLite's `typeof` function (column type) of the column named **????** (i.e. **TYPE_TYPECOLUMN** shows the type of the column **TYPE** etc)